# Please help me resolve my Excel Power Query / Custom Column Error

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery, customcolumn

I'm attempting to create an aging buckets analysis through the use of Excel Power Query.

Thus far I've created a column calculating the age of each record. The step I'm currently on is to categorize each record into age buckets such "31-60 days overdue" etc. This is being done though the use of a custom column with the following formula:

`=if [Payment Due Date] >180 then "over 180 days due" else if [Payment Due Date] <= 180 and [Payment Due Date] > 150 then "151-180 days overdue" else if [Payment Due Date] <= 150 and [Payment Due Date] > 120 then "121-150 days overdue" else if [Payment Due Date] <= 120 and [Payment Due Date] > 90 then "91-120 days overdue" else if [Payment Due Date] <= 90 and [Payment Due Date] > 60 then "61-90 days overdue" else if [Payment Due Date] <= 60 and [Payment Due Date] > 30 then "31-60 days overdue" else if [Payment Due Date] <= 30 and [Payment Due Date] > 0 then "1-30 days overdue" else if [Payment Due Date]<= 0 and [Payment Due Date] > -30 then "1-30 days overdue" else if [Payment Due Date] <= -30 and[Payment Due Date] and [Payment Due Date] > -60 then "31-60 days overdue" else if [Payment Due Date] <= -60 and [Payment Due Date] > -90 then "61-90 days overdue" else if [Payment Due Date] <= -90 and [Payment Due Date] > -120 then "91-120 days overdue" else if [Payment Due Date] <= -120 and [Payment Due Date] > -150 then "121-150 days overdue" else if [Payment Due Date] <= -150 and [Payment Due Date] > -180 then "151-180 days overdue" else if [Payment Due Date] <= -180 then "over 180 days overdue" else 0`

But I get the following error: `Expression.Error:  *We cannot apply operator < to types Number and Date. Details: Operator=< Left=180 Right=5/3/2021*`
here are some pictures for you to assess
[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jjh5Y.png)
[Custom Column Formula View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJckI.png)

Comment: Add a custom column that subtracts the due date from today's date, then use that instead of the due date in your calculation.

Comment: Rory... You just made me realize that I used the wrong column/field. Dude! Thank you. Thats such a dumb mistake glaring at me

Answer (score 0):

=if [Days Past Due Date] >180 then "over 180 days overdue"
else if [Days Past Due Date] <= 180 and [Days Past Due Date] > 150 then
"151-180 days overdue"
else if [Days Past Due Date] <= 150 and [DaysPast Due Date] > 120 then
"121-150 days overdue"
else if [Days Past Due Date] <= 120 and [Days Past Due Date] > 90 then
"91-120 days overdue"
else if [Days Past Due Date] <= 90 and [Days Past Due Date] 60 then
"61-90 days overdue"
else if [Days Past Due Date] <= 60 and [Days Past Due Date] > 30 then
"31-60 days overdue"
else if [Days Past Due Date] <= 30 and [Days Past Due Date] > 0 then "1-
30 days overdue"
else if [Days Past Due Date] <= 0 and [Days Past Due Date] > -30 then
"1-30 days due"
else if [Days Past Due Date] <= -30 and [Days Past Due Date] > -60 then
"31-60 days due"
else if [Days Past Due Date] <= -60 and [Days Past Due Date] > -90 then
"61-90 days due"
else if [Days Past Due Date] <= -90 and [Days Past Due Date] > -120
then "91-120 days due"
else if [Days Past Due Date] <= -120 and [Days> Past Due Date] > -150
then "121-150 days due"
else if [Days Past Due > Date] <= -150 and [Days Past Due Date] > -180
then "151-180 days due"
else if [Days Past Due Date] <= -180 then "over 180 days due"
else 0

Comment: I think the problem was that I was tired during my first attempt

Comment: You can greatly simplify your existing formula.  `... else if [Days Past Due Date] <= 180 and [Days Past Due Date] > 150 then ... => else if [Days Past Due Date] > 150 then ...`  And there may be an even simpler algorithm.